# Unable to connect (IPv6)

Tags: networking, firewall, ipv6

I couldn't find an answer or solution to my question in existing questions/answers on the net, so I have to write down my problem hoping that some expert spots the problem. Anyway here it goes.

I have 2 Ubuntu machines, configured that so that ipv4 is disabled  and only IPv6 is enabled. One of them is the DUT the other the Tester.

DUT's configuration:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback
auto ens1f0.101
iface eth1.101 inet6 static
    address fd53:7cb8:383:101::121
    netmask 48
```

Testers's configuration:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback
auto eth1.101
iface eth1.101 inet6 static
    address fd53:7cb8:383:1ff::141
    netmask 48
```

They are both connected over an unmanaged L2 switch and I don't disable the network manager (as a utility as a side information)

Now, both Nodes can ping each other with ping6, like:

```
On Tester: ping6  -c 3 -I eth1.101 fd53:7cb8:383:101::121
On DUT: ping6  -c 3 -I ens1f0.101 fd53:7cb8:383:1ff::141
```

As I wanted to test the nodes with `iperf3`, it fails and I know that firewalls are disabled on both nodes.

On DUT I start iperf3 with:

```
iperf3 -6 -s -p 7001 -B fd53:7cb8:383:101::121
```

On Tester:

```
iperf3 -6 -c fd53:7cb8:383:101::121 -p 7001 -u  -B fd53:7cb8:383:1ff::141 -b 10M -t 1
```

On Wireshark attached to `ens1f0` at DUT I can see the TCP packets coming from Tester with correct VLAN ID set, with correct destination address and port settings, Client tries to establist connection with Server but Server does not react.

When I run netstat -ant, it shows me something like:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 fd53:7cb8:383:101::7001 :::*                    LISTEN
```

But when I run nmap on Tester to scan ports on DUT, it returns nothing saying:

```
sudo nmap -e eth1.101 -6 fd53:7cb8:383:101::121 -Pnr -p1-8000
```

gives me:

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-11-23 13:01 CET
Nmap scan report for fd53:7cb8:383:101::121
Host is up (0.00031s latency).
All 8000 scanned ports on fd53:7cb8:383:101::121 are filtered
MAC Address: A0:36:9F:04:36:44 (Intel Corporate)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 174.62 seconds
```

Now I don't know what is wrong here.But I keep the eye on netstat report saying Local address `f"d53:7cb8:383:101::7001"` is listening but my Test machine prefix is `fd53:7cb8:383:1ff`. Could this be reason. Because when I change the Tester address to  `fd53:7cb8:383:101::xxx` It works with `iperf` and `Nmap` and etc.

That means I thought two nodes `fd53:7cb8:383:101::121` and `fd53:7cb8:383:1ff::141` with netmask 48 should be able to find each other and communicate....they do..Ping works and TCP packets are arriving but those TCP packets are not answered and NMAP says all ports filtered even I know that Firewall is disabled.

I hope someone knows the answer to this.

Thank You
Mtin

Comment: When you disabled the firewall did you reload it?

Comment: hmmm no but I do the experiment and change the Tester address from fd53:7cb8:383:1ff::141 to fd53:7cb8:383:101::141 on the console so that upper 64 bits of DUT and Tester matches --> (fd53:7cb8:383:101::) and after that without changing anything with firewall iperf works again....what is the deal here with IP addresses?

Comment: May be the switch was the issue!

Comment: this is good idea....why not..hmmmm but again....I see that TCP packets are arriving at target...so switch cannot be the reason...I can capture the packets at DUTs interface with wireshark

Comment: IPv6 expects subnets to be /64. No more, no less. If you change this, you will have subtle breakage which is difficult or impossible to fix.

Comment: Thanks alot for this tip....Do you also know some reference document(s) where I can read about such rules...Again thank you!

Comment: Why does ping still work?

Comment: @MetinYerlikaya The reason ping works could be that it bypass some parts of the kernel networking stack.